# C# code for Outlook Folder Dialog box with check boxes to select contact folders

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-object-model

I C# I need a dialog box that will allow a user to select certain folders.  Ideally I would like a dialog box that will show only the contact folders and allow the user to select a certain subset of them.

Answer (score 3):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184616.aspx):

```
Outlook.Folder folder = Application.Session.PickFolder();
```

You also could get all folder recursively and build your own form to pick subset (and use any filtration you want and add ability to add new one).